# Configure vscode task to copy a file after parcel watch

Tags: javascript, build, watch, parceljs, vscode-tasks

> **EDIT**: I don't want to use grunt or gulp for this, and neither do I want to configure a parcel-bundler. I have used all of those before,
>   and I would like to try using vscode tasks for this.

I have a working parcel watch npm task to build my files into a dist folder. Due to some reasons I need to copy a file from the dist folder to another folder after every build. I have configured another npm task for that, called "copy".

I am now trying to configure a vscode task to run this "copy" task after every build from the watch task.

I have already configured a watch task for this, however, it only runs the "copy" task when I terminate the watch task with ctrl-c.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "copy",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "windows-build",
      "path": "frontend/",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "watch",
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "watch",
      "path": "frontend/",
      "isBackground": true,
      "problemMatcher": {
        "background": {
          "activeOnStart": true,
          "beginsPattern": "> parcel watch \\.\\/src\\/index\\.html --public-url \\/public\\/dist -d \\.\\.\\/public\\/dist",
          "endsPattern": "√  Built in \\d+\\.\\d+s\\."
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "label": "build",
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn":["watch","copy"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this error message in the "output" tab

```
Error: the description can't be converted into a problem matcher:

{
  "background": {
    "activeOnStart": true,
    "beginsPattern": "> parcel watch \\.\\/src\\/index\\.html --public-url \\/public\\/dist -d \\.\\.\\/public\\/dist",
    "endsPattern": "√  Built in \\d+\\.\\d+s\\."
  }
}
```

Not sure why. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is:

You have defined your `watch` and `copy` tasks as a sequence. So `copy` will only execute, if `watch` has finished. Problem is: `parcel watch` is an endless process, as it watches for file changes, until you abort it manually. So `copy` will never start until `watch` exits.

Solution : Drop `"dependsOrder": "sequence"` from your task, so VS Code executes both tasks [in parallel](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_sequential-dependency-execution). First task `watch` starts Parcel in watch mode. The second task `copy` (`npm run windows-build`) should start another watcher, which watches your dist folder and copys your specific files from dist to another folder. E.g. that could be [`nodemon`](https://github.com/remy/nodemon):

```
"scripts": {
  "windows-build":"nodemon --watch dist -x \"cp x y\""
}
```

**Alternative: Use of [`buildEnd`](https://parceljs.org/api.html#events) hook of the Parcel API**

...would save you a watcher, if you wanna give it a try.

```
const bundler = new Bundler(...);
bundler.on('buildEnd', () => {
  // start your copy task on each rebuild,
  // e.g. with node childprocess spawn
});
// Call this to start bundling
bundler.bundle();
```

Comment: well... the question is about using VScode tasks feature to do this. But your idea of using a second watcher certainly points to a direction I've not thought of, and it does solve the issue.

Comment: As far as I know (and after some google searches later), VS Code doesn't offer a file watch feature accessible via public API. Internally it seems to be using some fork of chokidar: github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/master/package.json#L49. You can only provide feedback to VS Code that some background task is running, in order to let VS Code produce a result in problems panel with `problemMatcher`. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_background-watching-tasks . You will have to choose a watching feature like mentioned `nodemon` or Parcel API yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On my side i use concurrently

```json
    "start-nw": "npm run copy && concurrently --kill-others  \"npm start\" \"npm run nw\"",
    "start": "parcel src/index.html --no-autoinstall",
    "nw": "nw ./dist --remote-debugging-port=9222",
    "copy": "node tasks/copy.js -nwp plugins -d",
```